# Can I add artist images to the Android MediaStore?

Tags: android, android-image, mediastore

I know that you can add images to the Image MediaStore fairly easily, but is it possible to associate them with an artistId from the Audio MediaStore? I'm looking to download artist images for all of the songs in the Audio MediaStore and was hoping to leverage the existing tables. Is there a good way to do this or will I need to create my own SQL Lite table to handle this? It would be nice if the Audio MediaStore included artist images along with the album images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [MediaStore.Audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html) content provider. Here you can save and share between application information about image, audio about every artist. Therefore [Artist table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Artists.html) in the MediaStore has just : Artist name, Artist key, Number of Albums, Number of Tracks [ check [MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.html)  ].

A clean way it is saving images with the [MediaStore.Images.Media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html) & [MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html).

A dirtier approach it might be to use  [MediaStore.Audio.Artists](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Artists.html) where [ARTIST_KEY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.html#ARTIST_KEY) you can save the Artist name as key and [ARTIST](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.html#ARTIST) you can save the image path.